# Conditional sum in SQL (SAS) (SUMIFS equivalent) - Part 2

Tags: sql, sas, sumifs

Let say I have to table:

Table1:

```
ID  Item
1   A
1   B
1   A
2   B
2   B
3   A
3   B
3   B
3   A
```

Table2:

```
ID  A   B   C
1   91  94  90
2   100 97  93
1   97  94  96
2   97  95  90
3   99  100 93
1   90  97  97
```

Now I would like to take the sum conditional for my table1 from table2 (when the ID by row and the Item match by COLUMN):

```
ID  Item    Want
1   A       278
1   B       285
2   A       197
2   B   
2   B   
3   A   
3   B   
3   B   
3   A
```

So that I have 278 is the sum of all item 1 in column A, 285 is the sum of all itme 1 in column B, 197 is the sum of all item 2 in column A.

So what am I supposed to do in SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are only the first three rows filled in?

Comment: I just give an example.

Comment: . . Your "example" is misleading.  Although I was guessing that, it is probably better to show just the first three rows and indicate that the rest follow the same pattern (say `. . .`).  Empty values are different from calculated values.

Comment: You still haven't fully described what  "sum conditional" means. That terminology is not familiar to me and I assume also unknown to most people.  I assume it is summing based on some condition being satisfied. What is the condition that you want to test?

Comment: Hi, sorry for my misleading terminology. In fact what I want to say is that the conditional sum, that is the sum based on 2 conditions: the matching in row (id) and matching in column (item).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` and conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.id, t1.item,
       sum(case when t1.item = 'A' then t2.A
                when t1.item = 'B' then t2.B
                when t1.item = 'C' then t2.C
           end) as want
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.item
```

Comment: What if I dont want to group my want table? In fact what I want is to add a column of result but keep the order of my old table?

Comment: @tmtran99 . . . (1) SQL tables, unlike SAS datasets, represent *unordered* sets.  They don't have an ordering.  (2) You can use a correlated subquery as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Proc MEANS` is built from the ground up for the sole purpose of computing statistics for aggregates.

Consider this example:

```
data have; input
ID $ A   B   C; datalines;
1   91  94  90
2   100 97  93
1   97  94  96
2   97  95  90
3   99  100 93
1   90  97  97
;

ods _all_ close;

proc means  data=have stackodsoutput sum;
  class id;
  var a b c;
  ods output summary=want;
run;
```

that produces data set

[image]